# I am trying generate a random color(javascript) and apply the result to a button when it is clicked. How do I incorporate my JS with my Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

// random color generator

```
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
```

//And this is my Jquery.  I just wonder how do I put them together?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("button").click(function(){

        $(this).css({'background-color':color});
   });
});
```

//My first question asked here, I'm new to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little Modified Version....of your code.
Try to put delimiter `,` in `split()` to avoid any possible error , and attach the `#` to the variable `color` , after the Loop has finished its operation.

```
function getRandomColor() { 
var letters ='0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F'.split(','); var color ; 
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
 color +=letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]; 
} 
color = '#'+color;
return color;
}
```

Since `#` must be placed at the beginning after accumulating all the letters in `color`.
The `getRandomColor()` will return the calculated value of variable `color` .

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("button").click(function(){ 
$(this).css({'background-color':getRandomColor()
  });
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Also, where do I place these two pieces of code?  Do they both go into the <title>, should I set the JS in a seperate file and refer to it?

Comment: <head> //operation</head><body> //operation </body> <script src='file.js'></script><script> //call click event handler </script>

Comment: Or your can place all your pieces of code in <script> // CoDes </script> after </body> tag or before closing it , it actually doesn't matter.

Comment: Kindly Set it As Answered (TiCK at the left side of my answer) if it solves your problem.

Comment: <script>
 
  $( document ).ready(function() {

  

$("button").click(function(){
       
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(',');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
   });
   





        $(this).css({'background-color':getRandomColor()});


   });

});



</script>

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your `getRandomColor()` function within your `click` event handler:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': getRandomColor()});
});
```